# RAILS 4 ACTIVERECORD Retrieve newest records by key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have a table in my DB (PostgreSQL) which is roughly as follows:

```
Currency    Rate    Created_at
USD         13.5    08/07/2014
EURO        18.5    08/07/2014
USD         13.3    08/08/2014
EURO        18.3    08/08/2014
USD         13.4    08/06/2014
EURO        18.4    08/06/2014
USD         13.7    08/05/2014
EURO        18.7    08/05/2014
```

What I want to do is get only the newest values for each Currency key ('USD', 'EURO')
In this example, the expected result would be:

```
USD         13.3    08/08/2014
EURO        18.3    08/08/2014
```

What I have tried:

```
BancomerTasa.order(:created_at).select("DISTINCT ON (divisa) *")
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidColumnReference: 
ERROR:  SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
(ERROR)

BancomerTasa.uniq.pluck(:divisa, :tasa)
(1.1ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "bancomer_tasas"."divisa"
, "bancomer_tasas"."tasa" FROM    "bancomer_tasas"
 => [["EURO", #<BigDecimal:7fd4941d66c0,'0.1812E2',18(18)>], 
    ["DOLAR", #<BigDecimal:7fd4941d64e0,'0.1352E2',18(18)>],
    ["DOLAR", #<BigDecimal:7fd4941d62d8,'0.1356E2',18(18)>], 
    ["EURO", #<BigDecimal:7fd4941d6148,'0.1814E2',18(18)>]]
(TOO MANY VALUES)

BancomerTasa.group(:id,:divisa).having('created_at = MAX(created_at)')    
(GROUPING BY ID MAKES NO SENSE TO ME SINCE THAT'S THE PK 
BUT IF I DON'T I GET THIS ERROR: 
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "bancomer_tasas.id" 
must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function)
```

I think I'm a little confused right now. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what are `:divisa`, `:tasa` ?

Comment: Oops, :divisa = Currency, :tasa = Rate. Sorry about that! I have the attributes in spanish and I tried to roughly translate it to english. BancomerTasa is the model.

Comment: The error you are getting, is really *interesting*. No idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the most recent `BancomerTasa` record for each currency use `where` to add a condition for the correct currency, `order` by created_at, and get the `last` record:

```
most_recent_usd = BancomerTasa.where(currency: 'USD').order(:created_at).last
most_recent_euro = BancomerTasa.where(currency: 'EURO').order(:created_at).last
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I didn't want to 'hard-code' the type of currency, what I wanted was to get the different types of currencies with their most recent rates in a single query. I'm having a lot of trouble getting it to work though so I might have to just do this and move on.

Comment: @bsilvacs Don't have to hardcode it though, can get currencies first then loop through each one.

Comment: @Iceman You are correct. Thank you so much for helping me get this working. Accepted as answer.